# How to determine the van't Hoff factor for different salts in water experimentally?

Tags: physical-chemistry, ionic-compounds, colligative-properties

> How do I experimentally determine the van't Hoff factor for different salts in water?

I'm going to dissolve each of sodium chloride, potassium chloride, and lithium chloride in $\pu{20 mL}$ of water to form $0.1$ molality standard solutions. I want to determine the actual van't Hoff factor for these ionic compounds. Theoretically, it is 2, but how do I find the actual value? I know that the formula for van't Hoff is actual number of ions/theoretical number of ions, but I don't know how to find the actual number of ions. Can someone please help?

**PS:** My experiment is about ionic association. I am trying to see, how it affects van't Hoff and therefore freezing point depression. I was initially going to find the depression and then use the formula to find van't Hoff, but this is too tedious.

Comment: Measuring the freezing point depression may be tedious. But it is the only way of solving this problem.

Comment: Osmotic pressure measurement might be easier @Maurice